# ftp on windows server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, ftp

Is it possible to have ftp server on windows server 2008 which is available from web browser. So that I can list files and download them using web browser.

I set FTP site set anonymous authorization port 21 but when I type :

ftp://my_ip:21 nothig happens :/

Im doing it on my new VPS

Comment: Very similar question http://serverfault.com/questions/37367/cant-connect-to-my-ftp-server-why

Comment: OK, Now I can connect to the FTP on the localhost but when I try to connect from other IP there is: Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to 91.210.131.166

Comment: If you're the person who manages this FTP, have a look at this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771012(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure NTFS permissions for the target directory are set correctly.  When using anonymous login, the server will use the service identity.  May sure that this identity is included in the permission set.